# Increase image dpi for publication purpose

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

The image is obtained from Nanonis software for a typical STM (Scanning Tunneling Microscopy) topography, so the image pixel is fixed by the settings of software, which is always 512 x 512 pixels. However, for publication purpose, often time we need to correct the image background via a home-built LabVIEW program (doing things like linear background subtraction).

The problem is the exported image after LabVIEW processing is giving us a very low DPI value (I think it's 72 dpi). But for any academia journals, they all kinda have requirement on the image dpi values, typically, at least, 300dpi is required for images in the article we submit. (And we've been trying to solve this by modifying the LabVIEW program, but it's too complicated, and so far no luck...that's why I realized Python might save our day...?)

So I'm wondering, can anyone help me write a Python code that define a function (LabVIEW can only call Python functions) to increase the dpi of an image(png), without altering the image sizes(width & height)?

(Maybe via `PIL` package? I'm not very familiar with that one unfortunately)
A PNG image sample is here:

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow isn’ a code-writing service. You should probably go searching for python code to resize/scale up an image.

Comment: @balmy She does not want to change the size. I also thought that was against the definition of dpi but in fact it is not

Comment: @Maggie I am not sure why you have to integrate with LABVIEW (don't know this software). Can you just process the png directly after the export without scripting inside LABVIEW ?

Comment: Q: What “size” is a pixel? A: A pixel doesn’t have a size, that’s determined by metadata. You want more pixels you’ll *have* to resize the image - sounds like you might also have to fiddle with the DPI to make it’s “size” the same at higher DPI

Comment: How big in real world coordinates do you want the resulting image to be at 300 dpi?

Comment: @martineau The sizes to print out the images, I think, it's depends on the publisher, however, they do only point out their required dpi for images and photos they accept. So we definitely need to follow the rule, however we do not want to "squeeze" our images too small...is there really no way around this problem?

Comment: The dpi is completely irrelevant until you want to print. If you want a print with 7 inch side at 300dpi, you need 2,100 pixels - that's all there is to it. If you only have 512, you will have to scale that up to 2,100 by guessing extra pixels.

Comment: @Mark: That is what I was trying to explain in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789584/increase-image-dpi-for-publication-purpose?noredirect=1#comment121571619_68789958) under @ log0's answer.

Comment: @martineau Cool - you're right on the money - as always 

Comment: Maggie: This can be done fairly easily with the PIL — if you can answer my question. You may have to ask the publisher how big the images will be in the publication (or at least get a range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want using the PIL. Note that the test image I used was the one in your question which is an RGB image, not a greyscale one, and therefore so is the converted image. The images would be a lot smaller if they converted to greyscale before resizing them (which PIL can also easily do).

The code also assumes the image is square. But could be extended do handle arbitrary sizes by following the same pattern independently for the width and height.

```
from PIL import Image


print_dpi = 300
print_size = 3.46  # Inches

filename = 'STM_topography.png'
new_filename = 'STM_topography_resized.png'

img = Image.open(filename)
print(f'{img.size=}')
width, height = img.size

new_size = int(print_dpi * print_size)
img = img.resize((new_size, new_size), resample=Image.BICUBIC)
# img.show()
img.save(new_filename, dpi=(print_dpi, print_dpi))
```

Comment: Magic happens!! Thanks!! I see that I have to `resize` it before saving it with `PIL`

Comment: @Maggie You do **not** want to do this. You should show the image in the paper at the resolution it was acquired in the microscope. This “trick” just adds lots of megabytes to the PDF of your paper, without adding any information. The publisher’s requirements for a minimal DPI is for generated images (a picture of a graph, for example), which otherwise would look blocky and ugly. You can tell the publisher that the image submitted is at its natural resolution, they will accept it.

Comment: @Maggie: If images from a STM don't qualify as generated images, I don't know what does, LOL. Chris is correct in the sense that this basically just changes the number of pixels in the images and sets its dpi metadata to 300 — per the last thing you [told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789584/increase-image-dpi-for-publication-purpose/68790808?noredirect=1#comment121572174_68789958). An alternative to doing that might be to just set its dpi to `round(512 / 3.46)`, which is `148`. Which is correct all depends on what the goal is.

Comment: @Maggie: The code in my answer computes a value that 1,038 pixels wide, so you might want hardcode the `new_size` to be `1040` to meet the article submission guidelines for figures. You can save the resized image as TIFF by changing `new_filename = 'STM_topography_resized.tif'` and using `img.save(new_filename, fomat='TIFF', dpi=(print_dpi, print_dpi))`. Before that, you may also also do a `img = img.convert('L', (1, 0, 0, 1))` to convert it to greyscale.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks all for the heads up, I see your points. I just want to explore my options here a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [Image.save](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) from PIL.

```
img.save(fn, dpi=(300,300))
```

I actually had to Google this because for me the dpi directly depended on the image scale and screen. However it seems that there is a lot of confusion around this term. It is used for different things and can also be set independently to the size as a hint for print size to the printer.

More info [here](http://www.dpiphoto.eu/dpi.htm)

Comment: Doing this will make the original 512 x512 image be considered `512/300` or `1.7` inches square. I think the way to do things would be to decide how big the image should be in real-world coordinates, then determine how many pixels the would require, and the scaling the images pixels to be the needed number —  besides providing the `dpi` param.

Comment: @log0 Thanks! I tried this, it turns out this "quick fix" sacrificed the image size. The original image was 7.1 inch height x 7.1 inch width, with a dpi of 72, after simply "upscale" the dpi number, now the image is with a dpi of 300 however the size became 1.7" by 1.7".  Again, I'm really confused that why Photoshop can make "magic", seems it can upscale the dpi while kinda preserving the sizes (Maybe that's why it's not free...) Anyway, requiring certain dpi for a publisher is understandable, however we wanna be able to present a "decent" size of images/photos for our papers as well...

Comment: @Maggie: Photoshop automatically does what I described in my comment.

Comment: @martineau The software (Nanonis) we are using to acquire such a STM image is setting the pixels for each image, and it's kinda "convention" in the Microscopy research field, 512 is the max pixels people usually set for their equipment.

Comment: @Maggie: If you have a .png image of 512 x 512 pixels and you can tell me what size in inches you would like it to be at 300 dpi, then I can show you how to do it with PIL.

Comment: @martineau Taking Nature Communication for example, it says: "A single column width measures 88 mm and a double column width measures 180 mm." So that means a figure of 3.46" (88mm) with a 300dpi , should have about 1040 pixel (square). Now we only have 512 pixels, how we "fill up" the missing pixels with `PIL` ?